# problema con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta MySQL en la que intento sumar todos los valores de las columnas que tienen el mismo nombre, me explico: como se puede ver en la imagen aparecen los campos nombre, monto, tipo, fecha ahora lo que quiero lograr es mostrar los registros de cada cliente como si fuera un "select * from table" pero que me muestre una suma de todos los valores de monto que pertenecen a  cada cliente en lugar de imprimir los 3 registros que imprimia dos.

[image: base de datos]

quedando asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería algo así: `SELECT MAX(nombre) AS nombre, SUM(monto) total FROM tuTabla GROUP BY nombre`. Como recomendación, deberías normalizar tu tabla. En lugar del nombre del cliente, sería mejor usar su id para identificarlo en la tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es relativamente sencillo, solo debes usar el comando SUM y agrupar por columna nombre.

```
SELECT nombre, SUM(monto), tipo FROM test GROUP BY nombre, tipo ;
```