# SUMAR LOTE IGUALES

Tags: mysql

Buen dia

tengo el siguiente reporte

```
ORDEN               DELIVERY    CODIGO      LOTE        QTY
22251103-28120897   700132180   K07WJ71-5G  MX0430BS1   36
22251103-28120897   700132180   K07WJ71-5G  MX0430BS1   36
22251103-28120897   700132180   K07WJ71-5G  MX0360DB1   3
```

Lo que necesito es que me sume los dos lote iguales es decir que el la suma del lote MX0430BS1 me de 72 piezas y me deje las 3 pzas del lote MX0360DB1

tendria que quedar asi

```
ORDEN               DELIVERY    CODIGO      LOTE        QTY
22251103-28120897   700132180   K07WJ71-5G  MX0430BS1   72
22251103-28120897   700132180   K07WJ71-5G  MX0360DB1   3
```

Alguien sabe como debe ser la formula'

de ante mano gracias y saludos.

Comment: Básicamente lo que parece que buscas un `group by` y un `sum()` sobre la columnas `QTY`, has intentado hacerlo? has tenido algún problema=

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [problema con mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328390/problema-con-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Si la verdad esto es bien trivial , puedes ver algo parecido que solicito otro colega en el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328390/problema-con-mysql)
para el caso tuyo quedaria algo asi como:

```
SELECT LOTE ,ORDEN, SUM(QTY) FROM tabla GROUP BY LOTE, ORDEN;
```

Comment: listo, corregido.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agrupar por las columnas que se mantienen estaticas, en este caso las 4 primeras y luego usar la funcion de agrupamiento SUM(), sobre la ultima columna que es la quieres sumar.

```
SELECT ORDEN, DELIVERY, CODIGO, LOTE, SUM(QTY) QTY
FROM TU_TABLA
GROUP BY ORDEN, DELIVERY, CODIGO, LOTE;
```

Reemplaza en el codigo "TU_TABLA", por el nombre de la tabla de la cual tomas los datos. En caso de que tu reporte salga de una consulta, reemplaza "TU_TABLA" por la consulta que te devuelve estos datos entre parentesis y debes asignarle un alias.

```
SELECT ORDEN, DELIVERY, CODIGO, LOTE, SUM(QTY) QTY
FROM () AS REPORTE
GROUP BY ORDEN, DELIVERY, CODIGO, LOTE;
```

Saludos.